# How to Authenticate Slack APP And Redirect To My Auth Server To Get tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Hi I am Trying to develop a slack app for my product .

Slack OAuth - I am able to get the access token from slack after user allows and install the slack app.

But Now i need to get my product login screen so that user can enter credentials which calls my oauth server along with slack user info . This is exactly like how google calender Slack App has a connect button which takes you to the login screen of gmail

Can someone throw some info.

Comment: I've been searching for the same type of thing, specifically for Google OAuth to auth users for access for managing google tasks. Fingers crossed someone can help out.

Comment: @NickBitzer did you guys had any luck ?